# How many threads does a dask worker use in a threaded scheduler?

Tags: python, dask

When running a test case with dask I see 400%+ CPU usage even though I specify 1 worker in multiple ways. On Activity Monitor in OSX I see 2 processes, one with 1 thread, the other with 8 threads with the ThreadPool. I see 2 process, 1 thread and 4 threads with `single-threaded`. Any idea what all these threads are for?

Related: [What threads do Dask Workers have active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618436/what-threads-do-dask-workers-have-active)

```
import dask
import dask.array as da
from dask.diagnostics import Profiler, ResourceProfiler, CacheProfiler, visualize
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def main():
    a = da.random.random(size=(20000, 1000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
    q, r = da.linalg.qr(a)
    a2 = q.dot(r)
    out = a2.compute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Profiler() as prof, ResourceProfiler(dt=0.25) as rprof:
        #with dask.config.set(pool=ThreadPool(1)):
        #with dask.config.set(num_workers=1):  # 1 worker, 400% usage
        #with dask.config.set(num_workers=1, scheduler='single-threaded'):  # 1 worker, 400% usage
        with dask.config.set(pool=ThreadPool(1)):  # 1 worker, 400% usage
            main()
    visualize([prof, rprof])
```

Edit: If I comment out the profilers and ThreadPool imports I got 1 process with 4 threads after specifying `num_workers=1, scheduler='single-threaded'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask is only running a single task at a time, but those tasks can use many threads internally.  In your case this is probably happening because your BLAS/LAPACK implementation is multi-threaded.

You can probably control this with environment variables like `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.  There are more specific environment variables depending on your BLAS implementation.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` shows 1 thread for 1 process in Activity Monitor. Thanks.